# Copying data from GPU to CPU - CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have problem with copying data from GPU to CPU. At the beginning I create variable in GPU space:

```
__device__ float gpu_array;
```

In this GPU function, I want to copy the data from od.fS[gi] (value = 0,43...) to gpu_array:

```
__global__ void Collide(.....){
....

//Streaming
    od.fS[gi] = fi_S;
    od.fN[gi] = fi_N;
    od.fE[gi] = fi_E;
    od.fW[gi] = fi_W;

    gpu_array = od.fC[gi];
}
```

End here is function to copy data from GPU to CPU:

```
void showData(){

cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float* temp_array = NULL;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol((void**)&temp_array, "gpu_array", sizeof(temp_array), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

float* cpu_array = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(cpu_array, temp_array, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("h_array: %f\n", *cpu_array);
}
```

In finally copies but wrong values (0.00000, -0.00000 etc.). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` call uses syntax that was deprecated and removed from CUDA at least 5 years ago. Consult some modern documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your use of `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`:

```
float* temp_array = NULL;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol((void**)&temp_array, "gpu_array", sizeof(temp_array), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

- you haven't allocated storage for data pointed to by `temp_array`
- we don't use quotes around the device symbol name anymore
- the destination pointer should be just a pointer, not the address of a pointer
- the remaining code around `cpu_array` is completely unnecessary

Correct usage would be something like this:

```
void showData(){

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  float* temp_array = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(temp_array, gpu_array, sizeof(float));

  printf("h_array: %f\n", *temp_array);
}
```

Note that in this example, `gpu_array` is a scalar quantity, and so we could  do something similar with `temp_array`:

```
void showData(){

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  float temp_array;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp_array, gpu_array, sizeof(float));

  printf("h_array: %f\n", temp_array);
}
```